# How to display nested Mongo documents with ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I have two schemas, one for User and another one for a Project. Each user can have multiple projects and projects can be shared between users.

Here they are:

```
var ProjectSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  description: String,
  path: String,
  users: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
  active: Boolean
});

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  username: {type: String, unique: false},
  email: { type: String, lowercase: true },
  role: {
    type: String,
    default: 'user'
  },
  projects: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Project'}],
  hashedPassword: String,
  provider: String,
  salt: String,
  github: {}
});
```

On a client side I have an authentication service, Auth, that can provide current user with `Auth.getCurrentUser()` and two services for accessing User and Project resources respectively.

How do I get to something like that?

```
<h1>{{currentUser.username}}' projects:</h1>
<ul id="project-list">
  <li ng-repeat="project in projects">{{project.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

Clarification. I Forgot to mention that User service has `listProjects` method that provides a user JSON with populated projects. Here's code for the service:

```
angular.module('myapp')
  .factory('User', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/users/:id/:controller', {
      id: '@_id'
    },

    {
            changePassword: {
                method: 'PUT',
                params: {
                    controller:'password'
                }
            },
            pushProject: {
                method: 'PUT',
                params: {
                    controller: 'project'
                }
            },          
            listProjects: {
                method: 'GET',
                params: {
                    controller: 'project'
                }
            },
            get: {
                method: 'GET',
                params: {
                    id:'me'
                }
            }
      });
  });
```

The server part works. I just can't figure out how to get controller to work for the HTML above.